# How to customize the action of backBarButtonItem in Swift (iOS 14.4)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios14, backbarbuttonitem

My application has one `UINavigationController` as the initial view controller, and  `RootViewControler` as the root view controller for `UINavigationController`.

Then I created `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`, so we can navigate from `RootViewController`, to `FirstViewController` and then `SecondViewController`.

The question comes on how to customize the action of the `backBarButtonItem` on the navigation bar. The default `backButtonItem` pops out the top view controller but I would like to show some alert before pop up.

I tried to add following code in `viewDidLoad` for `RootViewController`, `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`, but I am still having the default behavior for back button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hello", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
}
```

Wonder do I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customize the *action* of a back bar button item. It does just one thing: go back. If you want to write your own button that does something else, use a left bar button item (and possibly suppress the back bar button item).